# WebMvcConfigurerAdapter does not work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

This is WebConfig code I am working on:

```
package hello.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/greeting").setViewName("greeting");
    }
}
```

And this is my Application.class

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

It seems to be a spring-boot issue that these class methods don't get called in some systems. The corresponding issue is reported at:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2870

My question is, can we map resources mapped in this class, outside this class as a temporary workaround?

If yes, how do we do this?

**Update:** Following Andy Wilkinson's suggestion I removed `@EnableWebMvc` and the demo app started working. Then I tried stripping down project files one by one to see at what point error disappears. I found that I had two classes in the project, one, extended from `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and the second, from `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. removing the former class from the project fixed the error.

What I want to know is, why did this happen? Secondly, why doesnt this error appear on all systems?

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot you don't need `@EnableWebMvc` as that is already automatically done by Spring Boot. Is the bean constructed? Is it being picked up by your component-scan?

Comment: Yes bean is getting constructed. I forgot to mention one thing. When I rename WebConfig to MvcConfig, everything starts working. But this appears to be system specific workaround... It doesn't work for all systems.

Comment: Please add your application class. And have you tried with removing the `@EnableWebMvc` as that isn't needed in a Spring Boot application.

Comment: Ok.. I will add the application class. Yes I tried removing '@EnableWebMvc'...Doesn't still work

Comment: In which case it isn't working? One thing that is wrong is the fact that you use `SpringApplication` as the source, whereas it should be `Application`.

Comment: I added Application.java class

Comment: I changed that and still no change. Issue is that this same piece of code works on some systems and it doesnt work on others. All systems that i tested had ubuntu 14.04, eclipse luna and oracle java 8

Comment: Are you deploying this application or are you using the `main` method to run it?

Comment: Start with --debug and get the information on what matched. I suspect that there is a part of the Spring MVC auto config isn't properly detected. Either due to not being available or rights or something. Spring MVC is what is calling this, if that isn't available nothing will be called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `WebConfig` is in the `config` package and `Application` is in the `hello` package. `@SpringBootApplication` on `Application` enables component scanning for the package in which it's declared and that package's sub-packages. In this case that means that `hello` is the base package for component scanning and, therefore, `WebConfig` in the `config` package is never found.

To solve the problem I'd move `WebConfig` into the `hello` package or a sub-package, for example `hello.config`.

Your latest update on GitHub changed `WebConfig` from extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` to extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`. `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` is the class that is imported by `@EnableWebMvc` so annotating your class with `@EnableWebMvc` and extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` will be configuring things twice. You should go back to extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` as you were before.

Comment: You should really update the code in the question as well, otherwise this is going to get very confusing.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson thanks for pointing that out, I felt like the answer didn't match up with the question any more. I can recommend checking the question's version history if anyone else stumbles upon this, to see what the code looked like originally.

Answer (score 0):

In My spring boot application it just need a single annotation @CrossOrigin to the Contorller class.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@CrossOrigin
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String addUser(@RequestBody User user){
        userService.addUser(user);

        return "Success add user.";
    }
}
```